# Duplicate "new questions" notification emails

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, email-notification

There seems to be a bug in the tag notification emails for stack overflow.

I have recently been receiving two emails for a tag I was subscribed to.  Today, there were 4 new questions, and I received 5 identical emails listing those four questions.

Comment: can you forward those emails to team@stackoverflow.com so we can have a look?

Comment: @Jeff same thing happened to me, need my emails as well?

Comment: @shadow sure go for it

Comment: I have forwarded one of those emails.  The others are identical.

Comment: Also forwarded an email (and sorry for duplicate question).

Answer (score 1):

Marking this complete, since that entire structure has been replaced...this should no longer be an issue since we centralized all this notification "stuff".

Comment: I actually just got the same email 5 times over the span of a couple minutes this morning.  I'll send those along to the email mentioned in the comments above.